# Block other domains pointing to yours

Tags: linux, apache, mod-rewrite

I have domain abc.com and I noticed another domain not owned by me pointing to the same IP address as mine. It is ghosting mine, so when you visit that website it looks exactly as if you were on mine.

Any ideas of how to prevent that?

my vhost looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /path/to/site

        <Directory /path/to/site/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>


RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !example.com [NC]
RewriteRule .? - [F]

ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Did you try to validate host with mod-rewrite?

Comment: what do you mean by that? I haven't, not sure how!

Comment: How is your web site configured?

Comment: In the web server config you can add a check to block another domain. It depends on how your config looks like.

Comment: Set up an explicit vhost for each domain you want to respond to, and set the default vhost to inform the user or redirect to your own domain

Comment: added vhost info

Comment: why is this down voted?? I am looking for a legit answer here

Comment: @jww Exactly! VirtualHost is a development question. There are 2600 questions on Stack Overflow tagged VirtualHost and 83594 tagged apache

Comment: It's more a question for Server Fault

Comment: What is the output when you run this command `apachectl configtest`. It tests the Apache configuration files

Comment: @sun_jara AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Syntax OK

Answer (score -2):

Apache uses the `Host` field from the HTTP requests headers to know which vhost is requested (`Host` corresponds to apache `ServerName` or `ServerAlias`).

Try `apache2ctl -S`, it will give you an ouput containing something like:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server ip (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost ip (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost www.example1.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-vhost.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost www.example2.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/002-vhost.conf:1)
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf:2)
         port 443 namevhost 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf:2)
         port 443 namevhost www.example1.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/non-default-ssl.conf:2)
```

Now imagine my ip is 1.1.1.1:

Given those three `curl` commands:

```
1. curl http://1.1.1.1 -H 'Host: www.example1.com'
1. curl http://1.1.1.1 -H 'Host: www.example2.com'
1. curl http://1.1.1.1 -H 'Host: www.spoofexample.com'
```

First one, apache finds the corresponding `ServerName` in a vhost file and uses /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-vhost.conf to satisfy request

Second one, apache finds the corresponding `ServerName` in a vhost file and uses  /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/002-vhost.conf to satisfy request

Third one (your undesired mapped DNS), apache doesn't find the corresponding `ServerName` into any of its vhosts file, and uses /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf to satisfy request

The same logic applies to SSL vhosts.

PS1: `ServerName` for the default HTTP vhost has a value of `ip`, and there is no `ServerName` in the default SSL vhost. Apache just assumes a `127.0.1.1`, which is not the IP address it listens on (just telling so it's not more confusing).

PS2: To make a vhost the default one it must be the first by names sorted (000 -> 001 -> 002).

Answer (score -2):

It is not possible somebody can ghost your account.
Suppose I am domain owner of abc.com  from hostgator. In order to host it on godaddy.com  I have to  go to domain controller put the godaddy  nameservers there. Then on hosting i create a website with same name.
You should not  hosting a real domain with ipaddress also. always use name servers which will prevent all those configuration.
Please check this page for redirects
https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/385/2237/how-to-redirect-a-url-for-a-domain
Are you hosting a domain from your local computer ?